# Why is JSON outputting out of order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, synchronization

I'm am trying to get a list of weather information for 8 locations. I'm using a weather API that accepts longitude and latitude and spits back json output with the weather info for that location. I feed the coords in order 0->7 but when json processes the data it comes back in a seemingly random order. I assume it's because some process faster than others and json is outputing what it gets back as it gets it. The output is correct, only the order is wrong.

```
var loc = null;
var body = "";
var campuses = new Array(8);
campuses[0] = "34.47242,-84.42489,1";
campuses[1] = "33.81488,-84.62048,2";
campuses[2] = "34.27502,-84.46976,3";
campuses[3] = "33.92987,-84.55065,4";
campuses[4] = "34.03433,-84.46723,5";
campuses[5] = "34.08362,-84.67115,6";
campuses[6] = "33.91124,-84.82634,7";
campuses[7] = "34.10409,-84.51804,8";

function getWeather(campusArray)
{
    body += '<p class="topTitle">Campus Weather</p>';
    var cSplit = new Array();
    cSplit = campusArray.split(',');
    var loc = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q="+cSplit[0]+","+cSplit[1]+"&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=0a05fff921162948110401&callback=?"; 
    $('#content').html('asdf');
    $.getJSON(loc,function(js)
    {
        var data = js.data;
        var humidity = data.current_condition[0].humidity;
        var tempF = data.current_condition[0].temp_F;
        var iconDESC = data.current_condition[0].weatherDesc[0].value;
        var iconURL = data.current_condition[0].weatherIconUrl[0].value;
        var windDir = data.current_condition[0].winddir16Point;
        var windSpeed = data.current_condition[0].windspeedMiles;
        var tempMaxF = data.weather[0].tempMaxF;
        var tempMinF = data.weather[0].tempMinF;

        body += '<p class="title">'+cSplit[2]+'</p>'+
        '<span class="body">'+tempF+
        ' '+windSpeed+
        '<img src="'+iconURL+'" /></span>';
        $('#content').html(body);
    });
}
getWeather(campuses[0]);
getWeather(campuses[1]);
getWeather(campuses[2]);
getWeather(campuses[3]);
getWeather(campuses[4]);
getWeather(campuses[5]);
getWeather(campuses[6]);
getWeather(campuses[7]);
```

I have also tried it as $.ajax

```
var loc = null;
var body = "";
var campuses = new Array(8);
campuses[0] = "34.47242,-84.42489,1";
campuses[1] = "33.81488,-84.62048,2";
campuses[2] = "34.27502,-84.46976,3";
campuses[3] = "33.92987,-84.55065,4";
campuses[4] = "34.03433,-84.46723,5";
campuses[5] = "34.08362,-84.67115,6";
campuses[6] = "33.91124,-84.82634,7";
campuses[7] = "34.10409,-84.51804,8";

function getWeather(campusArray)
{
    body += '<p class="topTitle">Campus Weather</p>';
    var cSplit = new Array();
    cSplit = campusArray.split(',');
    var loc = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q="+cSplit[0]+","+cSplit[1]+"&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=0a05fff921162948110401&callback=?"; 
    $.ajax({
        url: loc,
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(js)
        {
            var data = js.data;
            var humidity = data.current_condition[0].humidity;
            var tempF = data.current_condition[0].temp_F;
            var iconDESC = data.current_condition[0].weatherDesc[0].value;
            var iconURL = data.current_condition[0].weatherIconUrl[0].value;
            var windDir = data.current_condition[0].winddir16Point;
            var windSpeed = data.current_condition[0].windspeedMiles;
            var tempMaxF = data.weather[0].tempMaxF;
            var tempMinF = data.weather[0].tempMinF;

            body += '<p class="title">'+cSplit[2]+'</p>'+
            '<span class="body">'+tempF+
            ' '+windSpeed+
            '<img src="'+iconURL+'" /></span>';
            $('#content').html(body);
        }
    });
}
getWeather(campuses[0]);
getWeather(campuses[1]);
getWeather(campuses[2]);
getWeather(campuses[3]);
getWeather(campuses[4]);
getWeather(campuses[5]);
getWeather(campuses[6]);
getWeather(campuses[7]);
```

EDIT:

example of json output:

```
{ "data": { "current_condition": [ {"cloudcover": "100", "humidity": "93", "observation_time": "04:04 PM", "precipMM": "0.0", "pressure": "1009", "temp_C": "2", "temp_F": "36", "visibility": "8", "weatherCode": "116",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Mist" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0006_mist.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "WNW", "winddirDegree": "290", "windspeedKmph": "7", "windspeedMiles": "4" } ],  "request": [ {"query": "Lat 34.47 and Lon -84.42", "type": "LatLon" } ],  "weather": [ {"date": "2011-01-06", "precipMM": "9.3", "tempMaxC": "7", "tempMaxF": "45", "tempMinC": "2", "tempMinF": "35", "weatherCode": "113",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Sunny" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "WNW", "winddirDegree": "293", "winddirection": "WNW", "windspeedKmph": "20", "windspeedMiles": "13" }, {"date": "2011-01-07", "precipMM": "0.0", "tempMaxC": "6", "tempMaxF": "44", "tempMinC": "0", "tempMinF": "31", "weatherCode": "116",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Partly Cloudy" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "WNW", "winddirDegree": "286", "winddirection": "WNW", "windspeedKmph": "25", "windspeedMiles": "16" } ] }}
```

Comment: Can you post the output json. I think it is a hash/assocaited array not an array so the order will always get mixed up and you will need to access elements by their key/values instead of the place in the array.

Comment: added the json output that is returned by http://www.worldweatheronline.com/

Comment: I'm sending each lat,long,title that stored in the array one at a time. the getWeather function isn't getting an array it's getting campuses[0] (for exmaple) so I'm feeding "34.47242,-84.42489,1" in the function then splitting that into an array so I can call the needed information faster than running a substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the getJSON callback you are using to be recursive:

```
var loc = null, body = "", var campuses = [
    "34.10409,-84.51804,8", "33.91124,-84.82634,7", "34.08362,-84.67115,6",
    "34.03433,-84.46723,5", "33.92987,-84.55065,4", "34.27502,-84.46976,3",
    "33.81488,-84.62048,2", "34.47242,-84.42489,1"
]; // notice they are sorted backwards

function getWeather(campusArray) {
    var cSplit = [], loc;
    body += '<p class="topTitle">Campus Weather</p>';

    cSplit = campusArray.pop().split(',');  // popping the array removes it
                                            // from the length

    /* truncated for brevity.  Put your additional code here. */

    $.getJSON(loc, function(js) {
        /* truncated for brevity.  Put your code here. */
        if (campusArray.length) {
              getWeather(campusArray);
        }
    });
}
getWeather(campuses);
```

Comment: that's exactaly what I did right before I reloaded this page. LOL! Except I used a counter but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Ajax method and specify `async: false,` which would cause each call to block. The alternative would be to have placeholders for each campus result and to replace that for each as the results are returned, you'd need to extend your getWeather method to accept the target element but that would mean you could still use the async Ajax approach which would be better for your users.

Comment: $.ajax defaults to false. However, I've tried it both true and false and the output is never in order.

Comment: Curious, I'll have to experiment. Glad you have an answer though.